# TORQUE OF ARDUINO CAR

Tags: arduino

when an obstacle is in front, the Arduino car should turn left or right. But it is not turning properly. So, what can be the problem?

Comment: Welcome to *Robotics* SAI MANI, but I'm afraid that it is not clear what you are asking. We prefer *[practical, answerable questions based on actual problems that you face](https://robotics.stackexchange.com/help/dont-ask)*, so it's a good idea to include details of what you want to achieve, what you tried, what you saw & what you expected to see. Please take a look at [ask] & [about] for more information on how stack exchange works and work through the [*Robotics* question checklist](https://robotics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1302/37) to edit your question to make it clearer.

Comment: when an obstacle is in front, the Arduino car should turn left or right. But it is not turning properly. So, what can be the problem?

Comment: This is a fairly open-ended question because it could be a lot of things going wrong.  So this question is in danger of being closed.  Furthermore, you didn't provide nearly enough information for us to help you.  What is the mechanical chassis?  How is it wired?  What are the sensors to detect an obstacle?  What is the code doing?  There could be an issue at each of these levels.  I suggest you isolate the problem yourself and if you still have an issue, come back here with a more specific question.

Comment: @SAIMANI what does the question have to do with torque? ... please edit the title so that it matches the rest of the question